# Data::Dumper returned hash with a slash

Tags: perl, hash, hashref, data-dumper

So I have a line of perl code that reads like this:

```
my $stored_value = $foo->some_function($argument);
```

When I do a Dumper on it:

```
warn Dumper $stored_value
```

I receive this as a result.

```
$VAR1 = \{
             'foo' => 'abc',
             'bar' => '123'
};
```

Now, I've seen results like this:

```
warn Dumper $another_hash;
$VAR1 = {
      'foo' => 'bar',
      'baz' => 'quux'
    };
```

And if I wanted to get say, foo's value, I'd type in something like this:

```
warn Dumper $another_hash->{'foo'};
```

To get this as a result.

```
$VAR1 = 'bar';
```

Originally, I couldn't find anything through my Google searches, but just now, I made a little test script to play around with what I saw, and I found this out

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub test {
my $brother = {'Ted'};
$brother->{'Ted'} = 'brother';
return \$brother;
}

my $blah= test();
my $blah = ${$blah};
print Dumper $blah->{'Ted'};
print "\n";
```

Here are my results:

```
$VAR1 = 'brother';
```

I wanted to share what I had found incase someone else ran into the same thing, but what exactly did I see?

I saw how to do this in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References, but I just wanted some clarification on it.

Comment: Did you really declare `my $blah` twice?

Comment: This is minor, but ``\`` is a backslash, not a slash. Hopefully that will help you with searching in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but your output shows that `$stored_value` is a reference to a *scalar*, which, in turn, is a reference to a hash.

It is rarely useful to keep references to scalars so this may indicate a bug.

This short program shows how the value could have been created

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $href = {
  foo => 'abc',
  bar => '123',
};

my $href_ref = \$href;

print Dumper $href_ref;
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = \{
            'bar' => '123',
            'foo' => 'abc'
          };
```

And, by the way, it is usually more useful to use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) in preference to [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)